# php cookie not setting after logging out

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I'm making a website where some users can log in. I have my code create a simple cookie. Earlier my code was working and creating a cookie and allowing users to sign in. However, after I created a log out button and used it, I couldn't seem to create a cookie again (my website doesn't recognize a cookie and no cookie shows up in chrome when I check). I've already looked at all the other threads about creating a cookie and not being able to create a cookie, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is my code to create a cookie:

```
$userStuff = array('name' => $username,'password' => $password);
$date_of_expiry = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1 ;
setcookie( "user", $userStuff, $date_of_expiry, "/" ) ;
```

I know that the security is extremely lax and that I shouldn't store the password and such directly in a cookie, but I want to work on other things first. This code is before any html.

Here is my code where I changed the expiration date of the cookie to log out:

```
setcookie('user', $userStuff, time() - 3600, '/');
```

Comment: set the time of expiration on logout a past date

Comment: Found the problem. PHP decided it didn't want to use arrays in cookies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Apparently, you either cannot use arrays in cookies, or it just wouldn't let me use an array in my cookie this time.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

If you want to delete a cookie, you should pass a date in the past, for example:

```
setcookie('user', $userStaff, time() - 3600, '/');
```

Regards.

Comment: Sorry, that is actually what I did. I accidentally pasted my newer code where I tried to reset the expiration date there to see if I could recreate the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit aside the point, but why not use `$_SESSION`? It stores a cookie with a session token in your client's browser (when you run session_start) and most of the data is stored server side which is far more secure. For user auth data and tokens this is probably a better choice.

Example:

```
//First thing init the session
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

//Or retreive the data...

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

//Later when you want to log out just destroy the session:
session_destroy();
```